# Python heapify implementation run time

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, binary-heap

I am taking up a course on data structures and algorithms where I was supposed to implement the heapsort algorithm to run in a specified time frame. Below are the two implementations:

```
def generateSwaps():
size=self._n
    for root in range((size//2)-1,-1,-1):
        root_val = self._data[root]             # save root value
        child = 2*root+1
        while(child<size):
            if child<size-1 and self._data[child]>self._data[child+1]:
                child+=1
            if root_val<=self._data[child]:     # compare against saved root value
                break
            self._data[(child-1)//2]=self._data[child]   # find child's parent's index correctly
            self._swaps.append(((child-1)//2,child))
            child=2*child+1
            # print(child)
        self._data[(child-1)//2]=root_val       # here too, and assign saved root value
    return self._data
```

Here, self._n is the size of the input, self._data is a list of elements that need to formed into a heap.This implementation passes the test with much lower run time (largest iteration taking upto 0.32 seconds out of given 3 second time limit).

Below is the second code piece which fails miserably (with largest iteration taking upto 6 seconds)

```
for i in range(self._n//2 , -1, -1):
      child_index = 0
      if (2*i + 2) == self._n:
        child_index = 2*i + 1
      elif (2*i + 2) < self._n:
        child_index = self._data.index(min(self._data[(2*i) + 1],self._data[(2*i) + 2]))
      else:
        child_index = 0

      while self._data[i] > self._data[child_index]:
        b = 0
        print("child is smaller for n = " + str(i))
        print(child_index)
        if child_index == 0:
          break
        else:
          self._swaps.append((i, child_index))
          self._data[i], self._data[child_index] = self._data[child_index], self._data[i]
          if child_index <= n//2:
            i = child_index
          else:
            break
          if (2*i + 2) == self._n:
            child_index = 2*i + 1
          elif(2*i + 2) < self._n:
            child_index = self._data.index(min(self._data[(2*i) + 1],self._data[(2*i) + 2]))
          else:
            child_index = 0

        print("hello work")
        self._data[i], self._data[child_index] = self._data[child_index], self._data[i]
        print(self._data)
```

What I would like to understand is the reason for such large difference in running times. I assumed this could be due to the swapping of list items at every step in the while loop but since a list in python is basically an array, I realized swaps should be constant time steps too(This is my assumption. Please correct me if I a wrong).

Thanks in advance

Comment: `self._data.index(...)` - why are you calling `index`? That is so dang needlessly slow.

Comment: If you ever find yourself calling `index`, stop and try to find a better way to do things. It's usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. That solves my problem. I miscalculated finding index as a constant time operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Suggested by user2357112 and user2357112 in the comments above, The problem was the .index() operation in the line below.

```
child_index = self._data.index(min(self._data[(2*i) + 1],self._data[(2*i) + 2]))
```

Runitime of finding index of an element in an array is O(n) as it requires walking through the array until you find a first match in of the value.This causes the excessively long running time in the second implementation. In the first implementation, this has been replaced by directly comparing the values of the child under consideration and it's neighbouring child as shown below.

```
if child<size-1 and self._data[child]>self._data[child+1]:
   child+=1
```

Since arrays have constant time access to elements, the above implementation is constant time thus reducing the running time.

Comment: fwiw, user2357112 and user2357112 are the same person... :)